# How to access elements in a ArrayType in a writeStream?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, structure

I am building up a schema to accept some data streaming in.  It has an ArrayType with some elements.  Here is my StructType with the ArrayType:

```
val innerBody = StructType(
    StructField("value", LongType, false) ::
    StructField("spent", BooleanType, false) ::
    StructField("tx_index", LongType, false) :: Nil)

val prev_out = StructType(StructField("prev_out", innerBody, false) :: Nil)

val body = StructType(
StructField("inputs", ArrayType(prev_out, false), false) :: 
StructField("out", ArrayType(innerBody, false), false) :: Nill)

val schema = StructType(StructField("x",  body, false) :: Nil)
```

This builds a schema like"

```
root
 |-- bit: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- x: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- inputs: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- prev_out: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- spent: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- tx_index: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- out: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- spent: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tx_index: long (nullable = false)
```

I am trying to select the value from the "value element" in schema as it is streaming in.  I am using the writeStream sink.

```
val parsed = df.select("bit.x.inputs.element.prev_out.value")
.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

I have this but code above, but gives an error.

> Message: cannot resolve '`bit.x.inputs.element.prev_out.value`' given
>   input columns: [key, value, timestamp, partition, offset,
>   timestampType, topic];;

How can I access the "value" element in this schema?

Comment: You will have to explode the array `bit.x.inputs` and then select `exploded.element.prev_out.value` . thats all

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can exploded the array?

Comment: Rumesh has already presented my ideas as an answer below :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739072/spark-sql-how-to-explode-without-losing-null-values

Comment: Sorry,  I don't see the example.

Comment: the link you provided has the answer :) doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have data frame like this, first explode and followed by select will help you.

```
df.printSchema()
//root
//|-- bit: struct (nullable = true)
//|    |-- x: struct (nullable = true)
//|    |    |-- inputs: array (nullable = true)
//|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
//|    |    |    |    |-- prev_out: struct (nullable = true)
//|    |    |    |    |    |-- spent: boolean (nullable = true)
//|    |    |    |    |    |-- tx_infex: long (nullable = true)
//|    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val intermediateDf: DataFrame = df.select(explode(col("bit.x.inputs")).as("interCol"))
intermediateDf.printSchema()

//root
//|-- interCol: struct (nullable = true)
//|    |-- prev_out: struct (nullable = true)
//|    |    |-- spent: boolean (nullable = true)
//|    |    |-- tx_infex: long (nullable = true)
//|    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)

val finalDf: DataFrame = intermediateDf.select(col("interCol.prev_out.value").as("value"))
finalDf.printSchema()
//root
//|-- value: long (nullable = true)


finalDf.show()
//+-----------+
//|      value|
//+-----------+
//|12347628746|
//|12347628746|
//+-----------+
```