# PySpark 2.2 explode dropping null rows (how to implement explode_outer)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with some deeply nested data in a PySpark dataframe. As I'm trying to flatten the structure into rows and columns I noticed that when I call `withColumn` if the row contains `null` in the source column then that row is dropped from my result dataframe. Instead I would like to find a way to retain the row and have `null` in the resulting column.

A sample dataframe to work with:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, first, col, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(dataCells=[Row(posx=0, posy=1, posz=.5, value=1.5, shape=[Row(_type='square', _len=1)]), 
                 Row(posx=1, posy=3, posz=.5, value=4.5, shape=[]), 
                 Row(posx=2, posy=5, posz=.5, value=7.5, shape=[Row(_type='circle', _len=.5)])
    ])
])
```

I also have a function I use to flatten structs:

```
def flatten_struct_cols(df):
    flat_cols = [column[0] for column in df.dtypes if 'struct' not in column[1][:6]]
    struct_columns = [column[0] for column in df.dtypes if 'struct' in column[1][:6]]

    df = df.select(flat_cols +
                   [col(sc + '.' + c).alias(sc + '_' + c)
                   for sc in struct_columns
                   for c in df.select(sc + '.*').columns])

    return df
```

And the schema looks like this:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- dataCells: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- posx: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- posy: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- posz: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- shape: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _len: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: double (nullable = true)
```

The starting dataframe:

```
df.show(3)

+--------------------+
|           dataCells|
+--------------------+
|[[0,1,0.5,Wrapped...|
+--------------------+
```

I start by exploding the array since I want to turn this array of struct with an array of struct into rows and columns. I then flatten the struct fields into new columns.

```
df = df.withColumn('dataCells', explode(col('dataCells')))
df = flatten_struct_cols(df)
df.show(3)
```

And my data looks like:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|dataCells_posx|dataCells_posy|dataCells_posz|dataCells_shape|dataCells_value|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|             0|             1|           0.5|   [[1,square]]|            1.5|
|             1|             3|           0.5|             []|            4.5|
|             2|             5|           0.5|[[null,circle]]|            7.5|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

All is well and as expected until I try to `explode` the `dataCells_shape` column which has an empty/null value.

```
df = df.withColumn('dataCells_shape', explode(col('dataCells_shape')))
df.show(3)
```

Which drops the second row out of the dataframe:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|dataCells_posx|dataCells_posy|dataCells_posz|dataCells_shape|dataCells_value|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|             0|             1|           0.5|     [1,square]|            1.5|
|             2|             5|           0.5|  [null,circle]|            7.5|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Instead I would like to keep the row and retain the empty value for that column as well as all of the values in the other columns. I've tried creating a new column instead of overwriting the old when doing the `.withColumn` `explode` and get the same result either way.

I also tried creating a `UDF` that performs the `explode` function if the row is not empty/null, but I have ran into JVM errors handling `null`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import NullType, StructType

def explode_if_not_null(trow):
    if trow:
        return explode(trow)
    else:
        return NullType

func_udf = udf(explode_if_not_null, StructType())
df = df.withColumn('dataCells_shape_test', func_udf(df['dataCells_shape']))
df.show(3)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Can anybody suggest a way for me to explode or flatten `ArrayType` columns without losing rows when the column is `null`?

I am using PySpark 2.2.0

Edit:

Following the link provided as a possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739072/spark-sql-how-to-explode-without-losing-null-values) I tried to implement the suggested `.isNotNull().otherwise()` solution providing the struct schema to `.otherwise` but the row is still dropping out of the result set.

```
df.withColumn("dataCells_shape_test", explode(when(col("dataCells_shape").isNotNull(), col("dataCells_shape"))
                                              .otherwise(array(lit(None).cast(df.select(col("dataCells_shape").getItem(0))
                                                                                                              .dtypes[0][1])
                                                              )
                                                        )
                                             )
             ).show()

+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|dataCells_posx|dataCells_posy|dataCells_posz|dataCells_shape|dataCells_value|dataCells_shape_test|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
|             0|             1|           0.5|   [[1,square]]|            1.5|          [1,square]|
|             2|             5|           0.5|[[null,circle]]|            7.5|       [null,circle]|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: instead of using a udf can you try using spark's inbuilt `when`? it'll go something like,

`df = df.withColumn('dataCells', when(col('dataCells').isNotNull),explode(col('dataCells')))`

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back. Thanks for the idea. I also just noticed in Spark 2.3 and higher there is an `explode_outer` which would probably do what I need, but I'm stuck on 2.2.x for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark sql how to explode without losing null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739072/spark-sql-how-to-explode-without-losing-null-values). Though that post is not for pyspark, the technique is [not language specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739072/spark-sql-how-to-explode-without-losing-null-values#comment73803221_39739218).

Comment: I get the following error when trying the above and linked suggestions. `TypeError: condition should be a Column`. Written like `df.withColumn("dataCells", explode(
  when(col("dataCells").isNotNull, col("dataCells"))
    .otherwise(None)))`

Comment: @Alexander you are missing the parentheses at the end of `isNotNull()`

Comment: @Alexander I can't test this, but [`explode_outer`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode_outer-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) is a part of spark version 2.2 (but not available in pyspark until 2.3)- can you try the following: 1) `explode_outer = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode_outer` and then `df.withColumn("dataCells", explode_outer("dataCells")).show()` or 2) `df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")` and then `spark.sql("select *, explode_outer(dataCells) from myTable").show()`

Comment: Thanks @pault I'm not able to run this right now, but I'll let you know how it goes when I sit down and make the update. I like the idea of pulling in the explode_outer definition, but I'll give both a try just to have options for the future.

Comment: @Alexander related post on how to pull in java/scala functions: [Spark: How to map Python with Scala or Java User Defined Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181685/discussion-between-alexander-and-pault).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) for pointing me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233737/spark-how-to-map-python-with-scala-or-java-user-defined-functions) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684842/calling-java-scala-function-from-a-task) about mapping Python to Java. I was able to get a working solution with:

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column

def explode_outer(col):
    _explode_outer = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode_outer 
    return Column(_explode_outer(_to_java_column(col)))

new_df = df.withColumn("dataCells_shape", explode_outer(col("dataCells_shape")))

+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|dataCells_posx|dataCells_posy|dataCells_posz|dataCells_shape|dataCells_value|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
|             0|             1|           0.5|     [1,square]|            1.5|
|             1|             3|           0.5|           null|            4.5|
|             2|             5|           0.5|  [null,circle]|            7.5|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+

root
 |-- dataCells_posx: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dataCells_posy: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dataCells_posz: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dataCells_shape: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _len: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataCells_value: double (nullable = true)
```

It's important to note that this works for pyspark version 2.2 because `explode_outer` *is* defined in spark 2.2 (but for some reason the API wrapper was not implemented in pyspark until version 2.3). This solution creates a wrapper for the already implemented java function.

Answer (score 0):

for that complex structure would be easier to write a map function and use it in `flatMap` method of RDD interface. As a result you will get a new flatted RDD, then you have to create a data frame again by applying a new schema.

```
def flat_arr(row):
    rows = []
    # apply some logic to fill rows list with more "rows"
    return rows

rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(flat_arr)
schema = StructType(
    StructField('field1', StringType()),
    # define more fields
)
df = df.sql_ctx.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show()
```

This solution looks a bit longer than applying `withColumn`, but it could be a first iteration of your solution so then you can see how to convert it to `withColumn` statements. But in my opinion map function would be appropriate here just to keep things clear

Comment: Wouldn't using the RDD prevent the operations from being optimized by the catalyst optimizer?